# How to Find Documents in MongoDb where some fields are not null

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How to get list of Documents in MongoDb where some fields are not null eg. in Student collection Name, Age,Course should not Null other fields may contain null value.

:if any student Name or age or course contain null that must not come in result collection.

Comment: Why are you storing null values in the fields? You dont need them. MongoDB is schema-less so there is no point in storing null values if the field doesnt have values. You can simply ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
db.student.find({'name': {$ne: null}, 'course': {$ne: null}, 'age': {$ne: null}})
```

but as @Bipul said there's no need to store null values as MongoDB is schema-less. This query excludes from the result even the documents that don't have all these fields.